# Using url variables in dossier reporting gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dossier

I'm trying out the dossier gem for reporting.
https://github.com/adamhunter/dossier

Can't seem to find in any of the docs how to send over a url variable like
reports/test.csv?id=1

Have tried a few things, either get errors or blank values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer probably comes a bit too late but I thought I'd share for future googlers.

**tl;dr**

`/report/test?options[p1]=v1&options[p2]=v2` will be available inside the `TestReport` instance as `options[:p1] # => 'v1'` and `options[:p2] # => 'v2'`

**Explanation:**

When visiting a url such as `/reports/test.csv` you will trigger `TestReport` to be instantiated and ultimately receive CSV output.  If you would like to pass dynamic options in from the URL you would add them to the `:options` parameter which will be passed by the controller to the instantiated report.

All that is to say in the url use a format such as: `/reports/test.csv?options[id]=1&options[so_fancy]=true`.  This will cause `TestReport.new(id: '1', so_fancy: 'true')` to be called in the controller.  Inside of the report instance you will be able to access these options via the `options` hash.  I personally usually write accessors for my options because this allows me to handle typecasting.  All options come in as strings (because all controller parameters come in a strings).

For example:

```
class TestReport < Dossier::Report
  # NEVER interpolate options directly into your query
  # This uses id_where which will trigger query binding via the :id reference
  # your column names do not need to map to your options
  def sql
    "select * from foos where #{id_where} fancification = :fancy"
  end

  # conditionally adding this clause if id is present in options
  def id_where
    "id = :id or" if options[:id].present?
  end

  # makin' sure id is a number, probably superfluous, mainly for example
  def id
    options[:id].to_i
  end

  # the getter method names and the options keys do not need to correspond, 
  # don't forget all values come in a strings!
  def fancy
    options[:so_fancy] == 'true' ? true : false
  end
end
```

Hopefully this answers your question!

Comment: While I did give up on the Gem for now, this will be handy in the future.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your URL will need to look something like:

```
http://www.example.com/reports/test?options[id]=1
```

and you'll add a method with the same name as your option, in this case `id` to your report in order to capture that URL parameter:

```
class TestReport < Dossier::Report

  def sql
    "SELECT * FROM foos WHERE id = :id"
  end

  def id
    options[:id]
  end

end
```